# What exact order of store installed UWP application launch/activation phase? (HANG_ACTIVATION reports research)

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Recently I've faced a weird issue, increased HANG_ACTIVATION reports count when unable to reach Microsoft servers on startup. According to MS dashboard data a lot of our users was unable to launch application on their devices. I've found that issue were caused by failed requests (`POST https://licensing.mp.microsoft.com/v7.0/licenses/leases/renew` is one of them also azure purchase requests) to Microsoft servers, however, when you start the app from Visual Studio or disable internet connection the app starts just fine, that was definitely an issue related to some MS Store windows services.

After some further research into reports, I assume that the issue occurs when application didn't call onActivate event for a long time. It turns out, some windows service tracks time from application start to the Activation event, then shuts down the app by timeout. Unfortunately, it was hard to find any documentation on this (**please point me out if you know where I can find any info on this**). I've managed to replicate the same behavior when placing sleep for a ~2min in-between onLaunch and onActivate events. Besides according to network requests diagnostics, there is some try count for MS requests (when tested another app, I've got success run even on failed requests).

I have plenty of initialization code after launch and before onActivated is fired, this initialization process may took up 1 minute for application launch.
That's why I think it's relocation might help overcome the issue but I'm not sure exactly how the activation works under the hood.

Typical dashboard report:

```
Frame   Image   Function    Offset
0   3D4Medical.comLLC.CompleteAnatomy   HANG_ACTIVATION 0x0000000000000000  
1   unknown.dll [.ecxr] 0x0000000000000000  
2   ntdll.dll   NtWaitForMultipleObjects    0x0000000000000000  
3   KERNELBASE.dll  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx    0x0000000000000000  
4   combase.dll MTAThreadWaitForCall    0x0000000000000000  
5   combase.dll MTAThreadDispatchCrossApartmentCall 0x0000000000000000  
6   combase.dll CSyncClientCall::SendReceive2   0x0000000000000000  
7   combase.dll CSyncClientCall::SendReceive    0x0000000000000000  
8   combase.dll NdrExtpProxySendReceive 0x0000000000000000  
9   rpcrt4.dll  NdrClientCall2  0x0000000000000000  
10  combase.dll ObjectStublessClient    0x0000000000000000  
11  combase.dll ObjectStubless  0x0000000000000000  
12  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::ActivateInternal    0x0000000000000000  
13  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::Activate    0x0000000000000000  
14  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::ActivateForeground    0x0000000000000000  
15  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::ActivateApplication   0x0000000000000000  
16  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::ApplicationActivationFactory::Activate 0x0000000000000000  
17  rpcrt4.dll  Invoke  0x0000000000000000  
18  rpcrt4.dll  NdrStubCall2    0x0000000000000000  
19  combase.dll CStdStubBuffer_Invoke   0x0000000000000000  
20  rpcrt4.dll  CStdStubBuffer_Invoke   0x0000000000000000  
21  combase.dll ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction__lambda_ee1df801181086a03fa4f8f75bd5617f_ _ 0x0000000000000000  
22  combase.dll DefaultStubInvoke   0x0000000000000000  
23  combase.dll ServerCall::ContextInvoke   0x0000000000000000  
24  combase.dll AppInvoke   0x0000000000000000  
25  combase.dll ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID    0x0000000000000000  
26  combase.dll ThreadInvoke    0x0000000000000000  
27  rpcrt4.dll  DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf 0x0000000000000000  
28  rpcrt4.dll  RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker 0x0000000000000000  
29  rpcrt4.dll  RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWithObject 0x0000000000000000  
30  rpcrt4.dll  LRPC_SCALL::DispatchRequest 0x0000000000000000  
31  rpcrt4.dll  LRPC_SCALL::HandleRequest   0x0000000000000000  
32  rpcrt4.dll  LRPC_ADDRESS::HandleRequest 0x0000000000000000  
33  rpcrt4.dll  LRPC_ADDRESS::ProcessIO 0x0000000000000000  
34  rpcrt4.dll  LrpcIoComplete  0x0000000000000000  
35  ntdll.dll   TppAlpcpExecuteCallback 0x0000000000000000  
36  ntdll.dll   TppWorkerThread 0x0000000000000000  
37  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk 0x0000000000000000  
38  ntdll.dll   __RtlUserThreadStart    0x0000000000000000  
39  ntdll.dll   _RtlUserThreadStart 0x0000000000000000
```

All in all there **2 questions** I would like to find answers:

- Is my understanding of a Store installed app launch process right?
- Is initialization code relocating - from section after onLaunch to section after onActivate - a good approach to avoid future problems?

Comment: Hey @Faywang-MSFT hope you doing well! Any update from other engineers?

Comment: The activation process in detail is a black box, we don't know what happens in this process.